# How can I keep just the required files in zend framework for my application?

Tags: zend-framework

I'm not sure where to ask this, but frankly I'm using some libraries from the zend framework but at this moment have the entire framework in my library folder. Is there any script or exe out there which go through the application and tell which files are not being used and which are. Theres loads of includes and easy loading going on there.

Comment: Do you have a really small hard disk?

Comment: Lolz - not really, I was actually wondering that do I really need to deploy the entire library even thought I may be using just a few classes?

Answer (score 1):

The files that are included via `require_once` in the Zend Framework code are mostly required only if they are used.

But if you want to be 100% sure that only the *really* used ones are loaded (on the fly), use the autoloader in combination with a script that strips all the `require_once`, as shown in the ["Class Loading" part the official performance guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.classloading.html). There is a "How can I eliminate unnecessary require_once statements?" section. And this is a well know ZF optimisation technique, so it should be done anyway.